# Worked in software consulting firm for 2 months, should I put this on my resume?

Tags: career

I just recently got laid off from the role of PM in a software consulting firm. Should I include this experience on my resume? What are the pros n cons of this?

I am only looking for entry level PM jobs. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Leave it out, but mention during the verbal interview (personal or phone). A two-month long period is really short, I don't think you'll benefit from it when you are looking for new PM jobs. **When companies are looking for PMs they expect years of experience**, because this job simply requires experience.

There is another aspect. When **HR** looks through CVs they are processing a lot of information from different sources so they are using patterns to find suitable candidates. One pattern is the length of previous jobs. **If you spent only a short amount of time in a certain position they'll rank you lower**, because you don't have the experience, and you may not spend too much time at the company in the future either. If you don't put it there, they **may** get interested in you, and ask why you even applied for the job. This is your chance to explain it. Here is advice: if they write you an email don't write back, try to call them, because an email - like a CV - can be interpreted in different ways, and managers talk/call, they don't write emails in important situations.

Comment: Got it! I will leave it out. Right now I am only looking for entry level PM jobs so that I can get my foot in the door. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You highlight in your resume what will substantiate your capabilities for the specific job you are seeking.  Do not try to find rules to create a generic resume; in fact, do not create a generic resume.

There is an inherent bias for those job seekers that are currently under- or unemployed.  Including or excluding this piece of information will do nothing to curb that bias.  It is what it is and you simply will have to overcome it.  Maximize your chances through network rather than cold calling.  You have to do both, but focus your resources on the former.

The great thing about a PM job is that it is for projects.  Projects start and end.  Some last for a month, others for five years.  It is SOP for hiring managers in consulting and project management to review resumes from candidates with non standard job durations, as there are a ton of independents out there who jump from job to job with weird gaps in between.  It would not work for a bank manager, but it does work for a project manager.

Also, you say you are seeking an entry-level position.  Don't over think this.  It is entry-level.  Focus on substantiating that you are smart.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that one question you will certainly be asked is "why do you want to leave your current position?".

As an interviewer, I'd be a bit suspicious of you if at interview it turned out you'd not mentioned your most recent job on your CV.

Comment: Well, I got laid off from my current job. So that is why I am looking for some other opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't put it on.

REASONING: 
Puts you in a position of describing why you were only there for two months. You want a potential employer to focus on you, your skills, capabilities, what you can offer, etc.  This is particularly true for an entry level job.

Employment history for an entry level job is there to show that you can hold a job, have worked for someone before and generally didn't lazy-about for your student/pre-professional life.

Comment: I totally agree with your point here. I am not including it on my resume.

Answer (score 2):

I go along with the general view that you shouldn't include this job unless it added some weight to your resume. However, do be aware that some employers look for continuity or at least an explanation of gaps. I am currently working in a bank where this is the case, and every gap of more than a month has to be explained. If your resume and your explanation are out of step because you have excluded a job (no matter how short the duration), you won't get through the pre-employment security screening.

Comment: Thats informative. However, I relocated to a different city that is why I can tell the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the length of your resume and what you want to tall about.  If your resume is short, or it's your only PM experience, include it.  If your resume is long and there's not much to talk about, leave it out.

Comment: I have 3+ years of Software Development experience. The only PM experience is this 2 months. Should I mark it on my resume?

Comment: If you want to do PM work, sure.  If not, no.